# Storing object ID in HTML document: id vs data-id vs?

Tags: javascript, html, rest, dom

I would like to have an opinion on storing RESTful object IDs in document for accessing it later from JavaScript.

Theoretically speaking using `id` for addressing elements in HTML doesn't cut it anymore. Same element can be repeated twice on the page say in "Recent" and "Most Popular" queries which breaks the main point of using id.

HAML even has this nice syntax sugar:

```
%div[object]
```

becomes:

```
<div class="object" id="object_1">
```

But like I said, seems that it is not a good approach. So I am wondering what is the best way to store objects id in DOM?

Is this the current proper approach?

```
<div data-id="object_1">
```

Comment: "*which breaks the main point of using id*". Well, the "main point" of using ID is to **uniquely** identify an element. If you have a repeated element that you want to reference, use a *class* or *data-* attribute.

Comment: If you're storing application-specific information, using data attributes is appropriate.

Comment: Sorry, I have corrected the question. I am looking from the developer's standpoint of storing object IDs in document for accessing them later from JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

An ID is intended to uniquely identify an element, so if you have a case where you want to identify two or more elements by some common identifier, you can use ID but it may not be the best option in your case.

You can use IDs like:

```
<div id="d0">Original Div</div>
<div id="d0-0">Copy of original div</div>
<div id="d1">Another original Div</div>
<div id="d1-0">Another copy of original div</div>
<div id="d1-1">Another copy of original div</div>
```

and get all the *d1* elements using:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[id^=d1]');
```

or just *d1* divs:

```
document.querySelectorAll('div[id^=d1]')
```

You could also use a class:

```
<div id="d0" class="d0">Original Div</div>
<div id="..." class="d0">Copy of original div</div>
<div id="d1" class="d1">Another original Div</div>
<div id="..." class="d1">Another copy of original div</div>
<div id="..." class="d1">Another copy of original div</div>
```

and:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.d1')
```

Or use *data-* attributes the same way. Whatever suits.

You can also have a kind of MVC architecture where an object stores element relationships through references based on ID or whatever. Just think outside the box a bit.

Comment: I don't think I can use different IDs for copies of the object, they are rendered using the same partial so I am just thinking of jumping the `id` ship and use `data-id` from now on. However it is possible to have multiple id on the page without much issues, this makes HTML not valid.

Comment: Multiple IDs are only an issue if you need to use them for DOM or CSS. If that's not an issue, then likely you don't need them at all (on those elements).

Answer (score 2):

The purpose why data-selectors where introduces is because the users neednt want to use class or anyother attributes to store value.Kindly use data-selectors itself. In order to make it easy to access them use attributes selector i.e. [attribute='value']. PFB the fiddle for the same and also the example

[jsfiddle](http://jsbin.com/qamici/4/edit?html,js,output)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-git2.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body onload="call()">
  <div id="1" data-check='1'></div>
  <div id="2" data-check='1'>sdf</div>
  <div data-check='1'>sdf</div>
  <div data-check='1'>sdf</div>
  <div data-check='1'>sdf</div>
</body>
</html>

function call()
{

$("#1").html($('[data-check="1"]').length);

  $("#2").html( document.querySelectorAll('[data-check="1"]').length);

}
```

> Output: 5 5 sdf sdf sdf

Answer (score 1):

@RobG is right by using 'class' you can get array of elements in JavaScript as-

```
 var divs=document.getElelementsByClassName("className");
 \\And you can loop through it(`divs[i]`).
```

AND according to @RobG and @Barmar `data-*` attribute is also a good option.

But here is some point(just point, not negative or positive, its totally depends on your application need) I want to discuss:

**1]** `data-*` element is HTML5's new attribute. [Documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp)

**2]** To retrieve elements in javascript, You need to use `jQuery` or more bit of JavaScript, coz all direct function available have specific browser support:

Like `document.querySelector("CSS selector");` **IE8+**

`document.getElementsByClassName("className")`. **IE9+**

`document.querySelectorAll("CSS selector");` etc.

So, basically for this point you need to choose according to your app need and browser compatibility.

**3]** Performance issue is also there on selecting by `data-*` attribute... [Source](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/10/using-data-attributes-in-javascript-and-css/)

---

But, generally and if we go for latest application and selecting HTML5, `data-*` attribute + jQuery is a good option.

Comment: As far as I concerned I never use plain JavaScript, so it will be `$('[data-id="object_1"]')` or something. Plus as a side effect bonus, the object representation will be updated everywhere it appears on the page. Yes that worsens performance a tiny bit, but again I am not building anything gigantic.

Comment: @Nick You are right... :) having separate attribute for identification will be good for coding, coz `class` is for css selectors. That's why I said its totally depends on you, your app and your way of coding. I answered coz it may help someone else who don't want to use jQuery or more concern about performance or HTML4 validation etc.

Comment: There is [*getElementsByClassName*](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/domcore/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#dom-document-getelementsbyclassname) (though [*IE9+*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName)), *querySelectorAll* is [supported by IE8+](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll#Browser_compatibility) for CSS2 selectors like *.class*, and there are many libraries that implement CSS selectors, not just jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering about this too. Here's my POV using an example component.

#### CSS - styling across all buttons

Elements should not be referenced in JS using CSS classes because if you have multiple buttons that need to function differently, adding unique CSS classes for each component will get messy.

```html
<div class="my-component">
```

#### JS - Grab the component when it can only appear *once* on a page

While browsers may handle multiple `id` okay, it would harm maintenance since this would be unexpected behavior from an id.

```html
<div id="my-component">
```

```js
const myComponent = document.querySelector('#my-component')
```

#### JS - Grab the component when it can appear *multiple* times on a page

`ref` or `data-id` could both work. `ref` has been popularized by React and Vue, so it may be more familiar to developers.

```html
<div ref="my-component">
```

```js
const myComponents = document.querySelectorAll('[ref="my-component"]')
```

or

```html
<div data-id="my-component">
```

```js
const myComponents = document.querySelectorAll('[data-id="my-component"]')
```